# Html2Canvas ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, html2canvas

Estou tentando adicionar o html2canvas no meu ASP.NET Core web site.

Na [documentação](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started), eles dizem para usar:

```
npm install html2canvas
```

Quando eu executo esse comando, o `html2canvas` é instalado em:

```
myproject/src/myproject/node_modules
```

Quando eu tento usar os métodos do `html2canvas`, o seguinte erro ocorre no browser console:

```
html2canvas is not defined
```

Então, adicionei manualmente o arquivo `html2canvas.js` no meu projeto e referenciei o mesmo na página `html` desejada. `html2canvas is not defined` não apareceu mais, porém a página não é renderizada corretamente utilizando os comandos do `html2canvas`.

```
var element = document.getElementById("divPrint");

html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {
    // Export the canvas to its data URI representation
    var base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    // Open the image in a new window
    window.open(base64image , "_blank");
});
```

Qual é a forma correta de instalar? Via npm ou somente adicionando o arquivo `.js`?

Alguém poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que esteja utilizando apenas NPM, existem algumas possibilidades para utilizar os packages baixados.

É bom ressaltar que baixar os packages é apenas uma das tarefas que o NPM oferece para otimizar as tarefas repetitivas ao criar um site.

Vamos lá:

1. copiar o(s) arquivo(s) compilados para dentro dos seus fontes (muitos packages vem com os arquivos de criação, teste e distribuição)
2. fazer um link direto ao arquivo compilado, no seu exemplo seria algo como

`<script src="../node_modules/html2canvas/html2canvas.js"></script>`

As duas abordagens funcionam, mas veja qual será melhor quando você quiser atualizar os packages.